# Python: division error

Tags: python

Heres my method:

```
def geometricSum(commonRatio, firstTerm, lastTerm):
    return ((firstTerm - lastTerm) * commonRatio) / (1 - commonRatio)
```

Interpreter testing:

```
    >>> geometricSum(1.0,1.0,100.0)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
        File "F:\PortablePython_1.1_py3.0.1\sumOfGeometric.py", line 2, in geometricSum
          return ((firstTerm-lastTerm)*commonRatio)/(1-commonRatio)
    ZeroDivisionError: float division
```

Comment: Look at the parameters you are using, you are giving a value of 1 to commonRatio!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're dividing by zero. commonRatio is 1.0 so the denominator is 1-1.0 = 0.

Answer (score 9):

Haha man, I'm sorry to be blunt, but this has nothing to do with doubles. **You are DIVIDING BY ZERO!** You could have blown up the universe if it wasn't for python's exception handling!

Comment: @sdolan: I dunno, I heard that Jon Skeet can divide by zero, too.

Comment: @Chris probably just because Chuck Norris lets him, though

Comment: That's because Python spawns a parallel universe to run bytecode. And that's why the GIL is so hard to remove!

Answer (score 7):

```
1 - commonRatio = 1 - 1 = 0.
```

Division by 0 is not yet supported in python. or in math.

Answer (score 3):

Python told you what the problem is:

> ZeroDivisionError: float division

Please read the error messages. It says `ZeroDivisionError` because there was an `Error` trying to perform a `Division` by `Zero`. You are dividing by `1 - commonRatio`, which is zero at that point in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your commonRatio was 1 and so you were summing a divergent series.

Answer (score 1):

with those parameters you are trying to divide by zero...

```
commonRatio = 1.0

/ (1-commonRatio)

/ 0
```

this throws a ZeroDivisionError exception